# Как синтаксически правильно оформлять NuxtServerInit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Есть такой код в хранилище:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  z: 'sdfjkhskldjfhjskjdhfksjdhf',
});

export const mutations = {

  init_data_for_firmenistorie2 (state, uploadDbFirmenistorieData){
    state.z = uploadDbFirmenistorieData;
  },


};

  async nuxtServerInit ({commit}) {
    console.log('111');
    commit('init_data_for_firmenistorie2', 123)
  }


}
```

Вопрос:
Как правильно синтаксически оформить вызов `nuxtServerInit` таким образом что бы с помощью него можно было переписать значение стэйта `z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nuxtServerInit` - это `action` в `store`

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Ваш пример не работает, потому что

```
  async nuxtServerInit ({commit}) {
    console.log('111');
    commit('init_data_for_firmenistorie2', 123)
  }
```

Нужно поместить в `actions`, чтобы получилось так:

```
export const state = () => ({
  z: 'sdfjkhskldjfhjskjdhfksjdhf',
});

export const mutations = {
  init_data_for_firmenistorie2 (state, uploadDbFirmenistorieData){
    state.z = uploadDbFirmenistorieData;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({commit}) {
    console.log('111');
    commit('init_data_for_firmenistorie2', 123)
  }
}
```